# enabling caching of js/css files with nodejs/iis7 reverse proxy

Tags: caching, proxy, iis-7, reverse

I have a nodejs backend, site served through iis7 via reverse proxy as per this website: https://alex.domenici.net/archive/deploying-a-node-js-application-on-windows-iis-using-a-reverse-proxy.  In the node app i have a middleware layer to all get requests to cache content, like so

> res.set('Cache-control', `public, max-age=${period}`)

When running on my local machine i'm checking the headers via google developer tools and it does look like caching is working properly.  When I move it to production, i can't seem get it to work. On IIS i've configured the HTTP Response Headers to expire after 10 days.  My web.config looks like so (again per the link above)

> ```
>   <httpProtocol>
>     <customHeaders>
>       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
>     </customHeaders>
>   </httpProtocol>
>     <staticContent>
>         <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00"/>
>     </staticContent>
> </system.webServer> </configuration>
> ```

Tried various things without success.  The only possible lead i have at this point is from this thread
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/981bf691-ed6e-460a-9e99-af24fc8bfc0e/nodejsweb-apps-output-cache-not-working-for-node-web-app?forum=opensourcedevwithazure

but i have no idea how to make the suggested change in the web.config file.  A couple of notes, im currently just running my node app in the command prompt like so: node app.js, not as node bin/www as suggested in the link (having some odd issues).  Also, the site is still very much in development so on ssl.  Read that chrome might have some issues with it, but the problem is present in all browser tested (chrome, firefox, etc...)

Comment: Have you set up caching in iis? If not, please refer to this document: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching).

Comment: i tried adding what was suggested in the document, still not working.  i assume it has to do with the reverse proxy and url routing.  i was planning on moving to ubuntu at some point, maybe ill do it soon than later

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.